# IBM Kubernetes Services - Docker command not working

Tags: docker, kubernetes, websphere

I am working on POC to setup IBM API Connect v2018 on IBM Kubernetes Service.
I setup my IBM Kubernetes cluster environments and kubectl commands working fine.
Below command output/results are showing as expected:

```
ibmcloud login -a cloud.ibm.com -r eu-de -g Default
kubectl config current-context
kubectl get services --namespace=kube-system
ibmcloud cs clusters
ibmcloud cs cluster config --cluster myclsuter
kubectl get nodes
kubectl get pods -n kube-system
```

The Problem occurs when I am trying to install Docker Registry.
Trying to install Docker registry in IBM Kubernetes Services error exception thrown as below:

```
ibmcloud cr login 
FAILED
Could not locate 'docker'. Check your 'docker' installation and path.
```

When I type `docker` in IBM Cloud Shell:

```
-bash: docker: command not found
```

Can anyone please suggest how to install Docker on IBM Kubernetes Service...

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/

Comment: @uculc Does it solve your problem?

Comment: @Tarun - I am trying to install Docker registry in IBM Cloud Kubernetes Service.  I am still struggling it.. I am trying to run "ibmcloud cr login" but it shows Could not locate 'docker'. Check your 'docker' installation and path. Docker command not found.

Comment: @uculc After installing docker, have you started it with `sudo systemctl start docker` or
`sudo service docker start`?